# Making a POST call in R

Tags: r, api, httr

I have a rest API to which I want to make a POST call.

The API is 
"http://swift-rand-8888a.stg.corp.dummy.com/random/filter"

It doesn't need an Auth parameter.

The payload I am trying to send is:

> Payload:  {   "name": "Filter_1533141396310",   "shortName": "LHF",
>   "filterType": "==",   "value": {
>       "name": "completed",
>       "defaultValue": "completed"   },   "attribute": {
>       "vName": "status",
>       "vType": "LOCAL"   },   "transformerDependency": "",   "createdBy": "Aman" }

Header should be  {Content-Type=[application/json]}

I am always getting "bad request error".

My code looks like:

```
dummy<-"Payload:  {'name': 'Filter_1533141396310','shortName': 'LHF','filterType': '==','value': {'name': 'completed','defaultValue': 'completed'},'attribute': {'vName': 'status','vType': 'LOCAL'},'transformerDependency': '','createdBy': 'Prateek'}"

result <- POST("http://swift-rand-8888a.stg.corp.dummy.com/random/filter",
               body = dummy,
               add_headers("Content-Type=[application/json]"))
Output <- content(result)
```

Can someone help me with my mistake?

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine on my machine. Are you sure you're not behind a proxy or is some other network configuration issue ?

Comment: It works fine for me as well, It's just that Output is returning me "Bad Request" error, which should not happen. I guess I am doing something wrong with the payload.

Comment: I don't know because I can't reproduce your problem, but I think "Payload: " is useless... just pass the stuff between the `{}` since it's a valid json

Comment: That worked! Thanks @digEmAll. Although I am not getting the expected output, the successful API call can be seen on the server.